# Flutter version solved failed

Tags: flutter

I get this error msg and iam not sure how to solve this, i switched to stable channel and runned flutter upgrade:

Downloading ios tools...
Downloading ios-profile tools...
Downloading ios-release tools...
Running "flutter pub get" in projectname...
The current Dart SDK version is 2.18.2.

Because projectname requires SDK version >=2.19.0-197.0.dev <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because projectname requires SDK version >=2.19.0-197.0.dev <3.0.0, version solving failed.)
Exited (1)

Comment: What does the `pubspec.yaml`  file say at `environment: sdk:` ?

Comment: After i switched to channel master, everthing works, but the sdk environment is the same:
  sdk: '>=2.19.0-197.0.dev <3.0.0'

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought. I'd recommend just putting `sdk: ">=2.17.0 <3.0.0"` there. Or is there a reason why you specially need that version?

Comment: I can not remember, that i`ve edit the version number, but thanks for the advice. So instead of using environment: sdk: '>=2.19.0-197.0.dev <3.0.0' i should change it to sdk: '>=2.19.0 <3.0.0'?

Comment: @Sampelmind81 Yes!

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

check flutter and dart version:
flutter --version
dart --version

On mac go to Android Studio -> Preferences -> languages ​​& frameworks -> dart

(check here if it's pointing to something like "/Users/waldsonfagundes/development/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk" what matters if is if it is pointing inside the flutter folder dart-sdk).
The version appears just below the path (Ex.: 2.18.0)

On mac go to Android Studio -> Preferences -> languages ​​& frameworks -> flutter
check the version in this path too

the stable version today is:
Flutter 3.3.4 and dart 2.18.2

update the file:
pubspec.yaml

environment:
sdk: ">=2.18.0 <3.0.0"

dart version 2.19.0 and beta version still in flutter:
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=macos

downgrade the version:
flutter downgrade  (example: flutter downgrade v3.3.4)